# Deploying Grav CMS to Heroku

Tags: apache, .htaccess, heroku, grav

I'm using the RTFM Skeleton of Grav CMS and am trying to deploy it to Heroku, via GitHub.  Heroku completes deployment, says that no errors occurred, but Heroku is just giving me 500 errors.

Does anyone know how to get this working?  I was pointed toward the .htaccess file, but can't see anything obviously wrong (pasted below).  Many thanks in advance.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

## Begin RewriteBase
# If you are getting 404 errors on subpages, you may have to uncomment the RewriteBase entry
# You should change the '/' to your appropriate subfolder. For example if you have
# your Grav install at the root of your site '/' should work, else it might be something
# along the lines of: RewriteBase /<your_sub_folder>
##

# RewriteBase /

## End - RewriteBase

## Begin - Exploits
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Grav
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Exploits

## Begin - Index
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
## End - Index

## Begin - Security
# Block all direct access for these folders
RewriteRule ^(.git|cache|bin|logs|backup)/(.*) error [L]
# Block access to specific file types for these folders
RewriteRule ^(system|user|vendor)/(.*)\.(txt|md|html|yaml|php|twig|sh|bat)$ error [L]
# Block all direct access to .md files:
RewriteRule \.md$ error [L]
# Block all direct access to files and folders beginning with a dot
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
# Block access to specific files in the root folder
RewriteRule ^(LICENSE|composer.lock|composer.json|nginx.conf|web.config)$ error [F]
## End - Security

</IfModule>

# Begin - Prevent Browsing and Set Default Resources
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
# End - Prevent Browsing and Set Default Resources
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the fix wasn't the .htaccess file at all, I needed to include the following the require section of my composer.json and update the composer.lock.

"ext-mbstring": "*",